# Is it possible to use some short form in Postfix

Tags: front-end

### example 1

---

we can use `Information` , but can not use `?`

```
Sin // Information

Sin // ?
```

### example 2

---

we can use `StringJoin` but cannot use `<>`

```
"aa" <> 1 <> 2 <> "Ab" <> 123 <> "aend" /. <>-> ~~

"aa" <> 1 <> 2 <> "Ab" <> 123 <> "aend" /. StringJoin -> StringExpression

(*
    aa~~1~~2~~Ab~~123~~aend
*)
```

Comment: `~~` is not a symbol, but a binary infix operator that needs 2 arguments, so `foo // ~~` doesn't make sense, because it is incomplete. `a ~~ b` is parsed to `StringExpression[a, b]`, but `~~` (without any arguments) does not parse to `StringExpression`.

Comment: @rm-rf Yes, my post was not so exactly. Sometimes, my first response to do those `//` `/.` things is `?` `<>` because I've got used to do `?Sin`,`a<>b`, rather that `Information[]`. Actually I found this also couldn't been done ?/@{Sin}

Comment: That's because `?` is **not** an operator for `Information`. It so happens that just `?foo` by itself is parsed as `Information[foo]`, but otherwise, it does not behave like any other operator. To see that `?foo` is not actually a short form for `Information[foo]`, try `f[x_Symbol] := ?x` and then evaluate, say, `f[Sin]`. You'd expect it to be the same as `?Sin`, right? Check for yourself what happens. Besides, `?` is the operator for `PatternTest`.

Comment: Just to make it clear: if `?` had been an operator for `Information` it would have to be entered in prefix form as `?@Sin` or `?[Sin]` instead of `?Sin`. Only if the operator is called as `op@arg` can you postfix it as `arg//op`.

Comment: @rm-rf well Actually in my first post, there is no such word `Operator`...Anyway, good to learn that.

Comment: @IstvánZachar ok__.

Answer (score 1):

**Input Expressions**

There exists a definite grammar which specifies how your input should be converted to an internal form.

There are several operators which basically are overloads for internal functions:

> ```
> ^  -> Power
> +  -> Plus
> ~~ -> StringExpression
> etc.
> ```

What these operators all have in common is that they are binary operators, meaning their equivalent is a function taking two parameters.

The only two forms that do support binary operators are:

> ```
> f[x, y]     -> standard form
> x ~~ f ~~ y -> infix form
> ```

The other two forms support unary operators and they are special cases because of their precedence. When you write:

> ```
> f @ x + y  ==> f[x] + y
> x + y // f ==> f[x + y]
> ```

But you could write `f[x, y]` in prefix form, due to its higher precedence: `f@(x+y)`.

The last example `x + y // f` shows perfectly the problem here. It is translated to `f[x + y]` but if `f` would be the equivalent to `~~` it would be incomplete and therefore a syntax error.

I highly doubt that `?` is the operator equivalent for `Information`

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: I'm not sure the equivalence of `?` and `Information`, Sometimes I use `Definition`, when I cannot use ? in such case `?/@{Sin,Cos}`.
One reason about why I ask this question is that some newbie like me know only `?` in the beginning, and then after a long time, I know `Information` and `Definition`, what a bad thing.

Comment: Information prints the same information as ??.
Information is a function taking a symbol as a parameter, whereas ?? is not. ? and ?? are just input escapes.